# One sample Cohen's h variance to conduct a meta-analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size

I am performing a meta-analysis where my effects are mainly one-sample test against the chance level. Let's say that we have *n* subjects that perform several trials with a binary response (correct, wrong) and then I compute an accuracy index e.g. 0.7. All papers report a t-test against the chance level (e.g. 0.5) and then a cohen's d. I think that a more appropriate effect size measure could be a [cohen's h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_h) or more generally a difference between two proportions, in this case one sample proportion and a population (chance) proportion.
However, I'm not able to find a formula to compute the variance (for the inverse-variance weight) in this particular situation.